# Attempted to read or write protected memory calling a DLLImport function in VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, mfc

I've seen similar questions here, but none seems to apply to my case.

I created a MFC DLL that has a "login" function with the following header:

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool login( bool pBlnDesconectar );
```

I call that function from VB.NET (VS 2008, Framework 3.5) using this declaration:

```
<DllImport("ISAP.dll", EntryPoint:="?login@CISap@@QAE_N_N@Z", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Function login(ByVal pBlnDesconectar As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
```

The function is called and will run without problems, until it reaches the following call, which is a function from another DLL (SAP API).

```
std::vector<RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER> lstP;
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("ashost");     lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) _T("xxxx");
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("sysnr");      lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) _T("03");
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("client");     lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) _T("800");
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("user");       lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) strUser.GetBuffer();
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("passwd");     lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) strPass.GetBuffer();
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("lang");       lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) strLang.GetBuffer();
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("saprouter");  lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) _T("xxxx");
        lstP.push_back( RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER() ); lstP.back().name = (SAP_UC *) _T("use_sapgui"); lstP.back().value = (SAP_UC *) _T("1");

        RFC_ERROR_INFO objErrorInfo;
        // here is where it crashes with the message saying Attempted to read or write protected memory
        mObjConn = RfcOpenConnection( &(lstP[0]), lstP.size(), &objErrorInfo );
```

RfcOpenConnection has the following signature:

```
DECL_EXP RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE SAP_API RfcOpenConnection(RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER const * connectionParams, unsigned paramCount, RFC_ERROR_INFO* errorInfo);
```

DECL_EXP definition:

```
#ifndef DECL_EXP
#   if defined(SAPonLIN) && defined(__GNUC__) && defined(GCC_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY)
#     define DECL_EXP __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#   else
#     define DECL_EXP
#   endif
#endif
```

SAP_API definition:

```
#ifndef SAP_API
#ifdef SAPonNT 
#     define SAP_API _stdcall
#else
#     define SAP_API
#endif /* SAPonNT */ 
#endif /* SAP_API */
```

Types definitions:

```
typedef struct _RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER
{
    const SAP_UC * name;    ///< The name of the connection parameter, like ashost, user, client.
    const SAP_UC * value;   ///< The value of the given parameter.
}RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER,*P_RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER;

typedef struct _RFC_ERROR_INFO
{
    RFC_RC code;                    ///< Error code. Should be the same as the API returns if the API has return type RFC_RC
    RFC_ERROR_GROUP group;          ///< Error group
    SAP_UC key[128];                ///< Error key
    SAP_UC message[512];            ///< Error message
    SAP_UC abapMsgClass[20+1];      ///< ABAP message ID , or class
    SAP_UC abapMsgType[1+1];        ///< ABAP message type, e.g. 'E', 'A' or 'X'
    RFC_NUM abapMsgNumber[3 + 1];   ///< ABAP message number
    SAP_UC abapMsgV1[50+1];         ///< ABAP message details field 1, corresponds to SY-MSGV1 
    SAP_UC abapMsgV2[50+1];         ///< ABAP message details field 2, corresponds to SY-MSGV2 
    SAP_UC abapMsgV3[50+1];         ///< ABAP message details field 3, corresponds to SY-MSGV3 
    SAP_UC abapMsgV4[50+1];         ///< ABAP message details field 4, corresponds to SY-MSGV4 
}RFC_ERROR_INFO;

typedef struct _RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE {void* handle;} *RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE;
```

EDIT:

```
typedef wchar_t SAP_UC;
```

END EDIT

My guess is that the crash has something to do with the reference parameters I pass to RfcOpenConnection, but I couldn't find a function in the API that does not receive a parameter.

If I call the same "login" function of the MFC DLL from a C++ application, it runs fine.

Comment: Maybe not related, but are you sure that the C++ exported `login` function uses the stdcall calling convention?

Comment: Please provide the `typeddef` for `SAP_UC`

Comment: I don't understand why you think you have a problem with the `RfcOpenConnection` call, if `login` works fine from C++

Comment: It is an instance method of a C++ class.  You cannot pinvoke those, the *this* pointer isn't valid.  A hard crash is expected as soon as the method tries to access a class member.  You need a static function or use C++/CLI.

Comment: manuell, (1) regarding the calling convention, SAP_API is a macro for _stdcall; (2) I added the SAP_UC definition in the question as an edit now; (3) I made sure it crashes when calling RfcOpenConnection, I don't for sure why it only crashes when called from VB.

Comment: Hans, it makes sense. Yes, it is a class member. Let me try that.

Comment: Hans, you were correct, and, in fact, it was logical. It would crash when I assigned the result of RfcOpenConnection to mObjConn, which was a class member, non-static. Of course it worked in my C++ test application, because there, I created a class instance. In the other hand, it would make more sense if I could only export a class member function if it were static, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Hans Passant, my function was a class member, and was accessing other members from the class. Since I don't have an instance of the class, obviously "this" is not a valid pointer, and accessing any class members will result in a crash.